# How much time/material does it add up using a multi color 3D printer?

Tags: fdm, multi-material, color, pallete-2

I am wondering how much time/material would that add up using [AMS](https://us.store.bambulab.com/products/ams-multicolor-printing) or [Mosaic Pallet 3 Pro](https://www.mosaicmfg.com/products/palette-3-pro) with an FDM 3D printer compare to using a single filament?

I know it depends on how many colors we use and how we use the colors, but I am trying to estimate does it worth it to buy multi-color accessories regarding to using a single filament and hand painting the parts?